# What mount options can be used for read-only NFS export that is known not to change?

Tags: nfs

We have versions of datasets mounted from readonly snapshots of our enterprise file system, so we know the data on the mount never changes. Wondering what the best mount options are so NFS doesn't spend time checking for changes?

Comment: AFAIK there are neither mount nor export options that instruct the system that the file system being exported/mounted  is immutable. The only real option is "ro" (readonly) , which you're probably already using

Answer (score 0):

If the contents of the directories doesn't change, then you can bump the attribute cache lifetime to reduce the number of GETATTR requests. Moreover, the lookup cache positiv and negative results can be cached as well.

```
mount -o actimeo=3600,lookupcache=all srv:/data /mnt
```

The value is in seconds.

Of course, as by any configuration change you should measure the effect. Thus, you can use **nfsstat** utility to monitor  the number of sent GETATTR and READDIR requests.